# How do i upload laravel 5.4 to cpanel? and how to do npm run watch?

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-5.4

I am confused about how to put laravel 5.4 project into cpanel, and how do i perform npm run watch which is important, because i need to copy things from resources to public folder everything user does upload.

Answer (score 0):

first check in your control panel is available ssh access and if available than just upload your all folder and file on root except public folder now upload public folder content to your public_html i am upload screenshot that would be help full
http://prntscr.com/f9cto

Comment: Thank you for sharing..
I have put it in the folder as you recommended, however i am faced with error 500

Comment: something error with your service try to install new laravel in your webpage and check is it working you can install with help of composer connect your server with ssh and type composer is its working than you can type composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel name and than check is it working on your server or not